# How to show multiple functions on the same plot?

Tags: plotting

I tried this:

```
f[x_] := (x^2 - 1) (x^2 - 2)
g[x_] := (x^2 - 1) (x^2 - 2) + 3 sin (20 x)
p1 = Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 3}, PlotStyle -> Orange]
p2 = Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 3}, PlotStyle -> Blue]
Show[p1, p2]
```

However, that didn't produce a single plot with the two functions in different colors that I expected. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Functions in Mathematica start with a capital letter and use square braces, e.g. use `Sin[20 x]` instead of `sin (20 x)`.

Comment: Thanks, @user6014, of course! `Sin[20 x]` worked as expected.

Comment: You can use a single `Plot`: `Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, 3}, PlotStyle -> {Orange, Blue},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {0.5, 0.5}]]`

Answer (score 2):

After fixing the syntax error, you can also use your list of functions in the first argument and a list of colors in `PlotStyle` option setting to get the desired result more conveniently with a single `Plot` command:

```
Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, 
  {x, 0, 3}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Orange, Blue}, 
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]